# jquery prevent functions form executing, while an ajax post is in progress

Tags: ajax, jquery

I´m looking for a possibillity to prevent all functions from being executet while an ajax post is in progress. For example: I have a modal box where you can switch between two forms with a simple tab-navigation. When a user submits one of the forms, the data will be sent via ajax. So how can I avoid that the user can switch between the forms till the post is finished.
Is there a simple way to do that?

something like `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` during the ajax post.

Comment: you can do a simple boolean check. mark that boolean when on a request, then revert it after the request.

Comment: yes, I thought abaut that but my script is a little bit bulky and I hoped for a way to prevent all the other functions from executing. And I don't really want to extend my script too mutch. I thought mabe it's a common case and the jquery developers implemented some shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way to do that is just display an overlay. An element that takes up the whole screen and has no event handlers. The most popular option seems to be semi transparent div with a loading indicator to give user an idea about what's happening and that nothing will work on the website until request finishes.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NezTc/11/

Comment: I just stopped writing my half-written solution because this answer is just better in every way. Go with this, it's the right way to do it.

Comment: (Although it would nice you could show a code example like the other solutions).

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with this solution. Fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if other methods exist but i would bind a listener for all submits and check there if a flag for ongoingAjax request is set. This flag would be set by my ajax calls.

something like

```
$(function(){
    var onGoingAjaxRequest = false;

    $('form').submit(function() {
         if(!onGoingAjaxRequest) {
             return true;
         }
         return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can "cut off" all functions until a given point in time, but I know you can always:

1. Header all functions with `if(isPosting) return;` and add

   ```
   var isPosting = true
   $.ajax({ [...], complete:function(r){ // this is the ajax function
       isPosting=false;  
   }});
   ```
2. Or, overlay the whole thing and add a big preloader and a `Please wait...` message.